# Passing req data into Q promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, q

I'm having trouble with what I think are Javascript closures? I have an Express + Mongoose web app and am using the Q library for Promises.

I am wondering if it's possible to pass request data to the promise chain so that I can successfully execute the below code.

Currently, I am not able to set `review.reviewer` and `review.application`. The only solution I can think of currently is to append the request data to the `req.body` object so that all of this is handled on `Review.create` (see alternative solution code). Still, I am not sure if this is an ideal solution and whether or not it's possible to pass req data into a promise.

```
create: function(req, res) {
    console.log('Creating obj');

    Review.create(req.body).then(function(review) {
      Q.all([
        function() {
          review.reviewer = req.user.id;
          review.application = req.params.applicationId;
          return review.save();
        },
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(review.reviewer, {$push: {reviews: review._id}}).exec(),
        Application.findByIdAndUpdate(review.application, {$push: {reviews: review._id}}).exec(),
      ]).then(function() {
        req.flash('messages', {
          style: 'success', 
          type: 'Success',
          text: 'Your review has been submitted!',
        });
        res.redirect('/applications');
      }, function(err) {
        req.flash('messages', {
          style: 'danger', 
          type: 'Error',
          text: 'Something went wrong submitting the application!',
        });
        res.redirect('/applications');
      })
    });
  }
```

**Alternative solution code:**

```
req.body.reviwer = req.user.id;
req.body.application = req.params.applicationId;
Review.create(req.body).then(...)
```

Comment: what's wrong with `Review.create({reviewer: req.user.id, application: req.params.applicationId}).then()..` ?

Comment: It's totally valid! However, I'd have to concatenate is object with the other fields in my req.body object. I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you are making two mistakes:

- there should be a `return` in front of `Q.all` else, it would just assume `return null` i.e won't wait till Q.all is finished
- the first element of `Q.all` is a function, I am pretty sure that it has to be a promise,

I have placed the function details outside, hope it works now:

```
    ...
    Review.create(req.body).then(function(review) {
      review.reviewer = req.user.id;
      review.application = req.params.applicationId;
      return Q.all([
        review.save(),
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(review.reviewer, {$push: {reviews: review._id}}).exec(),
        Application.findByIdAndUpdate(review.application, {$push: {reviews: review._id}}).exec(),
      ]).then(function() {
    ...
```

Comment: The promise chain fails on `review.reviewer = req.user.id;`. In fact, if I tried to console.log the value, I get nothing (and there is a logged in user so the object is not undefined).

Comment: @tsurantino does, `req.user.id` have a value before you call `Review.create`?

Comment: Apparently it didn't! The code works. Thanks for your answer.